# Object to an Array Collection

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have an application that takes some database info and shoves it into a datagrid, or chart.

I've come across this error of having a single row and trying to use it in an array so I can use it in my app.  Its come to my attention that its a pretty common problem that people face, but I don't seem to be able to get around it no matter what a try.

My actionscript has a function that trots of to the database via ASP, and returns the data in the event - as below (obv I've removed some stuff - load of calls are made to the mssqlQuery function - only the one I have trauma with is below)

```
mssqlQuery("SELECT (CASE SLARag ,COUNT (SLARag)  as  Volume  FROM [CMI_ClientMI].[Portal].[BatchUpdate]","BusSegBuildSummary");}

public static function  mssqlQuery(sql:String,fid:String):void {
var http:HTTPService = new HTTPService;
var parm:Object = new Object;
parm.fas_sql = sql;
parm.fas_db = mssql_db;
http.url = mssql_url+"?irand="+Math.random();
// http.showBusyCursor = true;
http.request = sql;
http.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, mssqlResult);
http.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, mssqlFault);
http.method = "POST";
sqlToken = http.send(parm);
sqlToken.param = fid;
}

//Var for BusSegBuildSummary arraycollection
[Bindable]
public static var _BusSegBuildSummary:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();


//Case statement for BusSegBuildSummary
case "BusSegBuildSummary":


if( event.result.results.record is ObjectProxy ){
trace("this is object Proxy");

}
else{
   trace("this isnt object Proxy");
   _BusSegBuildSummary = event.result.results.record;

}

break;
```

So - if the result has more than one record in it - then we are fine - its the trace("this is object Proxy"); bit that is troublesome.
I think that I have to cast the object as an arraycollection and I've tried that a number of different ways with no success.

Any ideas? I've been struggling for a while now and I'm panicking!

Answer (score 1):

```
     
     if( event.result.results.record is ObjectProxy ){
       var obj:ObjectProxy = event.result.results.record as ObjectProxy;
       _BusSegBuildSummary = new ArrayCollection([obj.object]);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I think it might work. Just use ArrayUtil.toArray() to convert the ObjectProxy to an ArrayCollection.

```
// import array utils
import mx.utils.ArrayUtil;

// later on
var record:* = event.result.results.record;
if (record is ArrayCollection) {
  _BusSegBuildSummary = record;
} else if (record is ObjectProxy) {
  _BusSegBuildSummary = new ArrayCollection(ArrayUtil.toArray(record)); 
}
```